# Use SSH to access other hosts, but with destination routing

Tags: ssh, proxy

I'm setting up a reverse proxy using Traefik.  This works well, and results in a setup that supports the use of a URL (like https://backenddevice.domain.com) which then routes me to that backend device.

Question: Are there tools which allow a similar mechanism with SSH?  Eg:

1. connect user@backenddevice.domain.com, where DNS magic points me at my single 'SSH proxy'
2. SSH on my proxy accepts the login (maybe does ldap or other)
3. Connects me straight through to a specific onward device via telnet (or SSH) based on  "backenddevice" being in the connect (I don't know if this is even passed when connecting via SSH)
4. does not allow any interaction with the instance hosting the proxy (chroot jail also acceptable)

It would also be suitable to have user-backenddevice@domain.com, but the redirection/auth parsing would need to work somehow.

Inspired to ask by this question:
[How can I create an SSH login that delegates to telnet securely](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/204964/how-can-i-create-an-ssh-login-that-delegates-to-telnet-securely)
....but I have x000's of onward destinations and I'm trying to tidy up my firewall etc etc!

Thanks for any magic!

Comment: When I searched for 'ssh gateway' found this link: https://superuser.com/questions/1052394/ssh-gateway-server . Some other sources also use `ProxyCommand`, `ProxyJump` for connecting to a jumpbox. But I am yet unsure whether this prohibits shell access on jumpbox.